# CakePHP: Few questions about models, controllers an retrieving data

Tags: php, cakephp

Again me. I was using for a bit long time KohanaPHP and just can't get familiar with CakePHP, but working with it it's a pleasure for me.

First of all, I retrieve data from model, send it via controller to view and now got question. Do I really need to use following syntax of data in foreach loop?

```
$item['Model']['field']
```

It's a bit strange for me that I cannot use simply:

```
$item['field']
```

Second question... I need to use text core helper. Can I use it in view? I'm asking cause I got error about trying to use on a non-object.

I'm sorry for such newbie questions, but I was out of the coding game for over three years (worked as teacher) and it's really hard to get it sorted out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason you should be using the longer version;

`$item['Model']['field']`

is for when you're working with models that have associations. say in this case 'Model' belongs to a 'User', you'd be able to work with that mode's user data more clearly:

`$item['User']['field']`

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the start you could do:

```
$model = $item['Model'];
$field1 = $model['field1'];
$field2 = $model['field2'];
..etc...
```

That'll save you some typing.

Comment: Right. Didn't thought about this syntax. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. As for the second part of your question, not sure. heh, sorry.

Comment: The second part is solved. Oh my God... KohanaPHP made me crap, not programmer :-(   I forgot to put var $helpers = array('Text', 'Html'); in the controller... Please, no comments :-) Thanks for your time!